# ImportError when using tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow. I have tried to install and use `tensorflow-gpu` in ubuntu but keep getting the error below, please kindly help me to resolve it.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>()
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    242         else:
--> 243             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    244     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    342             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 343         return _load(spec)
    344 

ImportError: /home/iai/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined symbol: cudnnSetRNNDescriptor_v6

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d6579f534729> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>()
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import *
     25 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import
     26 

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>()
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 # Protocol buffers

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     70 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     71 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 72   raise ImportError(msg)
     73 
     74 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/iai/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/iai/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/iai/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/home/iai/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/iai/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /home/iai/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined symbol: cudnnSetRNNDescriptor_v6


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to reformat your post so that the code is displayed properly. You can do this by indenting it by four spaces. I also rephrased the question title to be more specific.

Comment: What version of CuDNN are you using ? Tensorflow need `CuDNN >= 6.0`

Answer (score 0):

looking at [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux) you need CuDNN 6.0, the CUDA 8.0 toolkit with associated drivers, a GPU with CUDA Compute Capability 3.0 or higher(you can check that [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)) and you should install the libcupti-dev library($ sudo apt-get install libcupti-dev).

I hope this helps you a bit further.

Comment: Thank you but i am still having the problem after the solution you recommended above